# How to transform nested dataframe schema in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with the following schema:

```
root                                                                            
|-- _1: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
|-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
```

I want to transform dataframe to the following schema:

```
root
|-- _1: struct (nullable = true)                                                                            
|    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`struct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=struct#pyspark.sql.functions.struct):

> `pyspark.sql.functions.struct(*cols)`
>
> Creates a new struct column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, col
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(_1=Row(key="a"), _2=Row(value=1))])

result = df.select(struct(col("_1.key"), col("_2.value")).alias("_1"))
```

which gives:

```
result.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- _1: struct (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
```

and

```
result.show()
# +-----+
# |   _1|
# +-----+
# |[a,1]|
# +-----+
```

Comment: Aha! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your `dataframe` is with following `schema`

```
root
 |-- _1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
```

Then you can use `*` to select all elements of *struct* *columns* into separate *columns* and then use `struct` *inbuilt function* to combine them back to one *struct* field

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select(F.struct("_1.*", "_2.*").alias("_1"))
```

you should get your desired output `dataframe`

```
root
 |-- _1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
```

**Updated**

More generalized form of above code if all the *columns* in original `dataframe` are *struct* is as below

```
df.select(F.struct(["{}.*".format(x) for x in df.columns]).alias("_1"))
```